# How to keep waiting Vue until getting data from firebase?

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I have a project that showing posts from a firebase realtime database. I use Vue, Vue-Router and Firebase Authentication. Firstly, when a user open the website, user see a login screen. In that screen page loads the posts from my database. Then when user login he/she routing to my Home.vue page. In here posts are showing there is no problem. But when user refresh the page, elements that are in the Home.vue are loading faster than my firebase data. I want to fix it.

That is my function that loads late from another javascript file:

```
function getData(data) {
  var posts = data.val();
  var keys = Object.keys(posts);

  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var id = keys[i];
    var user = posts[id].user;
    var text = posts[id].text;
    var date = posts[id].date;
    userPosts.push({
      id: id,
      user: user,
      text: text,
      date: date
    });
  }
  userPosts.reverse();
}

export var userPosts = [ ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You gotta look for lifecycle hooks in vue.js and use the one hook that triggers before/when the page is (re)loaded.. In it  you set a Promise with your firebase function, that triggers getData() when resolved and go through with the chosen lifecycle hook.